# OncreateView does not call when Activity get destroyed and re-run again

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm getting a strange problem with `Fragment` and `ViewPager`.

I have 1 ViewPager contains 3 Fragments.

1. When my app run for the first time. onCreateView on all my fragments get called and ViewPager works perfectly.

Code for initalizing ViewPager

```
private void initPager() { 

    mFragmentList.add(new MainSongListFragment());


    mFragmentList.add(new MainAlbumArtFragment());
    mFragmentList.add(new MainLyricsFragment());

    if (mFragmentList == null)
        mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    MainPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragmentList);
    mMainPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    myListViewInsideFragment= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
}
```

1. When I press back button and run app again. I get error at the code:

   myListViewInsideFragment= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);

It returns null because the onCreateView method on Fragment does not get called so all views on this fragment is not avaiable.

Code in My Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lo_my_list, container,
            false);
    mListView = (ListView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    return view;
}
```

My question is:
Why does not onCreateView method get called when Activity get destroyed and re-run again?.

Thank you.